# How to, in Compose, implement swipe if I want invoke action after swipe

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a problem with compose. I try implement simple calendar. I already have displayed month, and enabled change months by arrows.

[image]

Now I want to add change month by swipe.
I tried with `.swipeable`

This is sample:

```
val size = remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
val swipeableState = rememberSwipeableState(0)
val width = if (size.value.width == 0f) 1f else size.value.width - 60.dp.value * 2
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .onSizeChanged { size.value = Size(it.width.toFloat(), it.height.toFloat()) }
        .swipeable(
            state = swipeableState,
            anchors = mapOf(0f to 0, width to 1),
            thresholds = { _, _ -> FractionalThreshold(0.3f) },
            orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
        )
        .background(Color.LightGray)
) {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .offset { IntOffset(swipeableState.offset.value.roundToInt(), 0) }
            .size(60.dp)
            .background(Color.DarkGray)
    )
}
```

But this not work perfectly. I need to hold outside calendar area and I don't have idea how change state of month (that respond for display calendar).

My question is "how to implement swipe if I want invoke action after swipe".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can observe any state with [Side Effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects). In case you need to wait for an action to complete, you can use `if` + `DisposableEffect`:

```
if (swipeableState.isAnimationRunning) {
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            println("animation finished")
        }
    }
}
```

When the animation starts, I create a `DisposableEffect` and when it ends, `onDispose` is called, which means that the animation is finished.

In the case of your code, this will also be triggered at startup, because when you change the anchors after `onSizeChanged`, this also starts the animation. But you can check if the value has been changed, so it's not a big problem.

To solve your basic problem, you also need to have three states: left, middle and right.

---

A little off-topic, about that line:

```
val width = if (size.value.width == 0f) 1f else size.value.width - 60.dp.value * 2
```

1. You repeat this calculation every time you recompose, you shouldn't do that. You can use `rememeber` with `size.value.width` as the key, because `width` only needs to be recalculated when that value changes.
2. You are trying to get the pixel value from DP by multiplying by 2. This is wrong, you need to use Density.

---

So the final code can look like this:

```
enum class SwipeDirection(val raw: Int) {
    Left(0),
    Initial(1),
    Right(2),
}

@Composable
fun TestScreen() {
    var size by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
    val swipeableState = rememberSwipeableState(SwipeDirection.Initial)
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val boxSize = 60.dp
    val width = remember(size) {
        if (size.width == 0f) {
            1f
        } else {
            size.width - with(density) { boxSize.toPx() }
        }
    }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    if (swipeableState.isAnimationRunning) {
        DisposableEffect(Unit) {
            onDispose {
                when (swipeableState.currentValue) {
                    SwipeDirection.Right -> {
                        println("swipe right")
                    }
                    SwipeDirection.Left -> {
                        println("swipe left")
                    }
                    else -> {
                        return@onDispose
                    }
                }
                scope.launch {
                    // in your real app if you don't have to display offset,
                    // snap without animation
                    // swipeableState.snapTo(SwipeDirection.Initial)
                    swipeableState.animateTo(SwipeDirection.Initial)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .onSizeChanged { size = Size(it.width.toFloat(), it.height.toFloat()) }
            .clickable { }
            .swipeable(
                state = swipeableState,
                anchors = mapOf(
                    0f to SwipeDirection.Left,
                    width / 2 to SwipeDirection.Initial,
                    width to SwipeDirection.Right,
                ),
                thresholds = { _, _ -> FractionalThreshold(0.3f) },
                orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
            )
            .background(Color.LightGray)
    ) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .offset { IntOffset(swipeableState.offset.value.roundToInt(), 0) }
                .size(boxSize)
                .background(Color.DarkGray)
        )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

p.s. In case you don't need to animate anything during the swipe, I've moved this logic into a [separate modifier](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/0b34fac47ae04242868b8bc3afeb5dfe).

Answer (score 2):

Found this reusable `internal` implementation I found useful in the `androidx.compose.material` package that I copied into my projects.

```
/**
 * Create and [remember] a [SwipeableState] which is kept in sync with another state, i.e.:
 *  1. Whenever the [value] changes, the [SwipeableState] will be animated to that new value.
 *  2. Whenever the value of the [SwipeableState] changes (e.g. after a swipe), the owner of the
 *  [value] will be notified to update their state to the new value of the [SwipeableState] by
 *  invoking [onValueChange]. If the owner does not update their state to the provided value for
 *  some reason, then the [SwipeableState] will perform a rollback to the previous, correct value.
 */
@Composable
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
internal fun <T : Any> rememberSwipeableStateFor(
    value: T,
    onValueChange: (T) -> Unit,
    animationSpec: AnimationSpec<Float> = AnimationSpec
): SwipeableState<T> {
    val swipeableState = remember {
        SwipeableState(
            initialValue = value,
            animationSpec = animationSpec,
            confirmStateChange = { true }
        )
    }
    val forceAnimationCheck = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    LaunchedEffect(value, forceAnimationCheck.value) {
        if (value != swipeableState.currentValue) {
            swipeableState.animateTo(value)
        }
    }
    DisposableEffect(swipeableState.currentValue) {
        if (value != swipeableState.currentValue) {
            onValueChange(swipeableState.currentValue)
            forceAnimationCheck.value = !forceAnimationCheck.value
        }
        onDispose { }
    }
    return swipeableState
}
```

Usage:

```
val swipeableState = rememberSwipeableStateFor(
    isLocked,
    onValueChange = {
        isLocked = it
        /* any other logic */
    }
)

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .swipeable(
            state = swipeableState,
            anchors = anchors,
            thresholds = { _, _ -> FractionalThreshold(0.3f) },
            orientation = Orientation.Vertical
        )
) { ... }
```