# How to enable Compose snackbar's swipe-to-dismiss behavior

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-snackbar

Simple code below for showing the Compose Snackbar

This code correctly shows the Snackbar, when onClick event occurs.

```
 val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState() // this contains the `SnackbarHostState`
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier,
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState // attaching `scaffoldState` to the `Scaffold`
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch { // using the `coroutineScope` to `launch` showing the snackbar
                    // taking the `snackbarHostState` from the attached `scaffoldState`
                    val snackbarResult = scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                        message = "This is your message",
                        actionLabel = "Do something."
                    )
                    when (snackbarResult) {
                        SnackbarResult.Dismissed -> Log.d("SnackbarDemo", "Dismissed")
                        SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed -> Log.d("SnackbarDemo", "Snackbar's button clicked")
                    }
                }
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "A button that shows a Snackbar")
        }
    }
```

**How to dismiss snackbar on right/left-swipe?**

Answer (score 10):

The `SnackbarHost` has no such functionality. But you can extend it with the `nackbarHost` argument.

Also if you want the snackbar to disappear only with a swipe, you probably need to set the duration to `Indefinite`:

```kotlin
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier,
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    snackbarHost = { SwipeableSnackbarHost(it) } // modification 1
) {
    Button(
        onClick = {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                val snackbarResult = scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                    message = "This is your message",
                    actionLabel = "Do something.",
                    duration = SnackbarDuration.Indefinite,  // modification 2
                )
                when (snackbarResult) {
                    SnackbarResult.Dismissed -> Log.d("SnackbarDemo", "Dismissed")
                    SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed -> Log.d(
                        "SnackbarDemo",
                        "Snackbar's button clicked"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = "A button that shows a Snackbar")
    }
}
```

`SwipeableSnackbarHost` inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69103026/3585796)

```kotlin
enum class SwipeDirection {
    Left,
    Initial,
    Right,
}

@Composable
fun SwipeableSnackbarHost(hostState: SnackbarHostState) {
    if (hostState.currentSnackbarData == null) { return }
    var size by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
    val swipeableState = rememberSwipeableState(SwipeDirection.Initial)
    val width = remember(size) {
        if (size.width == 0f) {
            1f
        } else {
            size.width
        }
    }
    if (swipeableState.isAnimationRunning) {
        DisposableEffect(Unit) {
            onDispose {
                when (swipeableState.currentValue) {
                    SwipeDirection.Right,
                    SwipeDirection.Left -> {
                        hostState.currentSnackbarData?.dismiss()
                    }
                    else -> {
                        return@onDispose
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    val offset = with(LocalDensity.current) {
        swipeableState.offset.value.toDp()
    }
    SnackbarHost(
        hostState,
        snackbar = { snackbarData ->
            Snackbar(
                snackbarData,
                modifier = Modifier.offset(x = offset)
            )
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .onSizeChanged { size = Size(it.width.toFloat(), it.height.toFloat()) }
            .swipeable(
                state = swipeableState,
                anchors = mapOf(
                    -width to SwipeDirection.Left,
                    0f to SwipeDirection.Initial,
                    width to SwipeDirection.Right,
                ),
                thresholds = { _, _ -> FractionalThreshold(0.3f) },
                orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
            )
    )
}
```

Comment: TY for sharing :) I think typically a snackbar would auto dismiss after few seconds, but you also want to be able to swipe to dismiss it to, so you want both behaviours. 

With this solution I found that now, if you wait for automatic dismissal, the fade out animation is gone, the snackbar just disappears abruptly without animation. It's connected with this line at the beginning of the host:

```
if (hostState.currentSnackbarData == null) { return }
```

I guess this solution does not support both dismiss types?

Comment: Also probably worth noting that swipeable API has been replaced by Foundation's AnchoredDraggable APIs, and that there is a guide to complete this migration: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/AnchoredDraggableState

Answer (score 2):

**Material 2 solution**

Solved this by using [`SwipeToDismiss`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#SwipeToDismiss(androidx.compose.material.DismissState,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.collections.Set,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1)) Material component.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable fun AppSwipeableSnackbarWrapper(
  state: AppSnackbarHostState,
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  dismissSnackbarState: DismissState = rememberDismissState { value ->
    if (value != Default) {
      state.currentSnackbarData?.dismiss()
      true
    } else {
      false
    }
  },
  dismissContent: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
  LaunchedEffect(dismissSnackbarState.currentValue) {
    if (dismissSnackbarState.currentValue != Default) {
      dismissSnackbarState.reset()
    }
  }
  SwipeToDismiss(
    modifier = modifier,
    state = dismissSnackbarState,
    background = {},
    dismissContent = dismissContent,
  )
}
```

And then maybe you can use this wrapper like this or adapt it was you need:

```
snackbarHost = {
            AppSwipeableSnackbarWrapper(
              state = snackbarHostState,
              dismissContent = { AppSnackbarHost(hostState = snackbarHostState) }
            )
          },
```

**Material 3 solution**
*(Edit January 2024)*

Check [`M3Experiment2`](https://github.com/astamato/swipe-snackbar-experiment/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/showsnackbarsample/M3Experiment2.kt) implementation using [`SwipeToDismissBox`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/wear/compose/material/package-summary#SwipeToDismissBox(androidx.wear.compose.foundation.SwipeToDismissBoxState,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Any,kotlin.Any,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function2)).

Comment: "dismissSnackbarState.reset()" often doesn't get called, so I can show the Snackbar only once until I exit from the screen and come back. Is there a way to show the Snackbar again after it's dismissed?

Comment: For it to show again you need to reset it after swipe. What you mean by "often doesn't get called", do you think this is a bug on the library? on your code? In this snippet, it gets called every time the dismissSnackbarState.currentValue changes, for example when state changes from Default to DismissedToEnd or DismissedToStart depending swipe direction.

Comment: I expected "dismissSnackbarState.reset()" would get called whenever I swipe the Snackbar, but it didn't. But if I set a breakpoint in "rememberDismissState { ... }", "dismissSnackbarState.reset()" does get called. Not always, but often enough. But without a breakpoint, "dismissSnackbarState.reset()" never gets called (at least in my case), so I can show the Snackbar only once. Also, "confirmValueChange" in "rememberDismissState" isn't the last parameter (in Material 3 version I'm using), so I had to adjust the sample code to make it compile.

Comment: Instead of breakpoint, add a log, those are never ambiguous.
And yes, dismissSnackbarState.reset should get called whenever you swipe the Snackbar thanks to the state change in the launched effect. If thats not the case, you'd need to share a bit more code.

Comment: My example is pretty much a verbatim replica of the sample code (https://pastebin.com/K3bLiUUK). "dismissSnackbarState.currentValue" starts as "DismissValue.Default", but it never changes, so "dismissSnackbarState.reset()" doesn't get called even after I swipe to dismiss the Snackbar. Guide me what to look for.

Comment: Nothing strikes as obvious, i uploaded the full working sample here so you can see in context: https://github.com/astamato/swipe-snackbar-experiment hope it helps!

Comment: Yours works as expected, but mine doesn't. The difference is, your sample is using "androidx.compose.material", while I'm using "androidx.compose.material3". If you change "rememberDismissState", "SwipeToDismiss", and "DismissValue.Default" to "androidx.compose.material3.rememberDismissState", "androidx.compose.material3.SwipeToDismiss", and "androidx.compose.material3.DismissValue.Default", then you can easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: Gotcha, I can reproduce with the code here http://github.com/astamato/swipe-snackbar-experiment/pull/1/files I fixed with a launched effect removing the confirmValueChange lambda which in M3 runs at a different stage than in M2 
The fix:

https://github.com/astamato/swipe-snackbar-experiment/pull/2/files

The delay isnt great, but avoids a timing condition in which you see the snackbar snap back into place before fading. But it debounces and makes you unable to show snackbar for one second. Im trying to come up with a better solution.

Comment: Perhaps that's why setting a breakpoint was often effective in solving the problem. Thanks for looking into it. I still prefer "SwipeToDismiss" to other solutions. Hope we find a way to make it work with M3.

Comment: Hey there :) If you have a minute to spare, would u mind testing this again using latest code here https://github.com/astamato/swipe-snackbar-experiment/ ? The runnable is M3Experiment2 in MainActivity. It's updated to use latest M3 and SwipeToDismissBox. I think it works now, but would appreciate a second opinion. TY!

Comment: "M3Experiment2" looks great. A couple of minor comments. 1) When the Snackbar shows up and I do "press and hold, swipe, but don't swipe it off, just keep holding", the Snackbar disappears when the timer expires. If I don't let go of the Snackbar, then I'd say I'm not done with the Snackbar, so it would be great if it cancels the timer (and perhaps restart the timer if I stop holding). 2) The space between the Snackbar and the keyboard (if keyboard is shown) is wider than the space between the Snackbar and the bottom of the screen (if keyboard is not shown).