# Bidirectional Swipe using Swipeable Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using `Swipeable` in jetpack compose for left to right or right to left swipe gestures. But i am confused if i can pass both of them in a single swipeable method ?

```
 Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .swipeable(
                    state = swipeAbleState,
                    anchors = mapOf(0f to 0, sizePx to 1),
                    thresholds = { _, _ ->
                        FractionalThreshold(0.3f)
                    },
                    orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
                )
```

This will provide me left to right swipe and similarly if i pass `mapOf(0f to 0, -sizePx to 1)` in `anchor` it will provide me right to left swipe now I need to have both of them in my `Box` is it possible ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to, in Compose, implement swipe if I want invoke action after swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69101453/how-to-in-compose-implement-swipe-if-i-want-invoke-action-after-swipe)

Answer (score 2):

If you want both left and right then use following **anchors**:

```
    val anchors = mapOf(0f to 0, sizePx to 1, -sizePx to 2)
```

Comment: simple as that !

Answer (score 1):

try: anchors = mapOf(0f to 0, sizePx to 1, -sizePx to -1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).