# I need to use swipe to reveal and swipe to dismiss together with jetpack compose android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to use swipe to reveal when swiping right and swipe to dismiss when swiping left with jetpack compose android how can I achieve that ?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69103026/3585796).

Comment: gives me this error 
Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

Comment: Which exactly code gives you such an error? I've coped the the last code block from my answer and it works as expected. Add the code you've tried to this question

Comment: Why not just implement the default method of swipe to dismiss and modify it to by observing the "change in x"? Read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#gesture-and-animation)

Comment: I am using swipeToDismiss and swipeToReveal what I need is to cobine both actions on same item based on direction , do you get my question?

Comment: @Richard Onslow Roper Can you please give an example of how we can observe the change in x? Is there something for observing change in x on SwipeToDismiss?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found this very helpful lib [RevealSwipe](https://github.com/ch4rl3x/RevealSwipe) that have a very nice option to reveal from right and from left as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this. Try it yourself or I may as well help in a while, but it should be fairly easy. Try it.

```
fun Modifier.swipeToDismiss(
    onDismissed: () -> Unit
): Modifier = composed {
    val offsetX = remember { Animatable(0f) }
    pointerInput(Unit) {
        // Used to calculate fling decay.
        val decay = splineBasedDecay<Float>(this)
        // Use suspend functions for touch events and the Animatable.
        coroutineScope {
            while (true) {
                // Detect a touch down event.
                val pointerId = awaitPointerEventScope { awaitFirstDown().id }
                val velocityTracker = VelocityTracker()
                // Stop any ongoing animation.
                offsetX.stop()
                awaitPointerEventScope {
                    horizontalDrag(pointerId) { change ->
                        // Update the animation value with touch events.
                        launch {
                            offsetX.snapTo(
                                offsetX.value + change.positionChange().x
                            )
                        }
                        velocityTracker.addPosition(
                            change.uptimeMillis,
                            change.position
                        )
                    }
                }
                // No longer receiving touch events. Prepare the animation.
                val velocity = velocityTracker.calculateVelocity().x
                val targetOffsetX = decay.calculateTargetValue(
                    offsetX.value,
                    velocity
                )
                // The animation stops when it reaches the bounds.
                offsetX.updateBounds(
                    lowerBound = -size.width.toFloat(),
                    upperBound = size.width.toFloat()
                )
                launch {
                    if (targetOffsetX.absoluteValue <= size.width) {
                        // Not enough velocity; Slide back.
                        offsetX.animateTo(
                            targetValue = 0f,
                            initialVelocity = velocity
                        )
                    } else {
                        // The element was swiped away.
                        offsetX.animateDecay(velocity, decay)
                        onDismissed()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
        .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.value.roundToInt(), 0) }
}
```

Comment: I am really new to the whole compose thing , and I dont know how to use this code you provided

Answer (score 0):

I've solved such a problem with using this library dependency

```
de.charlex.compose:revealswipe:1.0.0
```

See [here](https://github.com/ch4rl3x/RevealSwipe)

Comment: it didnt solve the problem,
first I still cant have two types of dismiss on the same card 
second it limits the options you can reveal to just one icon

Answer (score 0):

Check this implementation [here](https://proandroiddev.com/swipe-to-reveal-in-jetpack-compose-6ffa8928a4c2) without additional libraries.

https://proandroiddev.com/swipe-to-reveal-in-jetpack-compose-6ffa8928a4c2

```
@Composable
fun DraggableCardComplex(
    card: CardModel,
    isRevealed: Boolean,
    cardOffset: Float,
    onExpand: () -> Unit,
    onCollapse: () -> Unit,
) {
    val offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val transitionState = remember {
        MutableTransitionState(isRevealed).apply {
            targetState = !isRevealed
        }
    }
    val transition = updateTransition(transitionState)
    val offsetTransition by transition.animateFloat(
        label = "cardOffsetTransition",
        transitionSpec = { tween(durationMillis = ANIMATION_DURATION) },
        targetValueByState = { if (isRevealed) cardOffset - offsetX else -offsetX },
    )
    
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset { IntOffset((offsetX + offsetTransition).roundToInt(), 0) }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectHorizontalDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                   ..
                }
            },
        content = { CardTitle(cardTitle = card.title) }
    )
}
```